# Get value from input in a table

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function create_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main_table");
    var n = table.rows.length;
    var m = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = n;
    var cell = row.insertCell(1);
    cell.innerHTML = "<input size=10>";
    for (i=2; i<m; i++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = "<input size=4>";
    } 
}

function print_values() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main_table");
    for (i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
        console.log(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

However, when I print values I get `<input size="10">`.

The problem is that when I create a row, I add manually some value to a table (in a webpage) and I want to print those values in a log. How can I access those values, but not html of the input?

I probably can assign an id to each input form and then access `value` keyword, but thought maybe it could suffice using table cells.

Answer (score 2):

The `input` element is a child of the table cell. And you have to use `.value` to get the value of an input, not `.innerHTML`.

```
console.log(table.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the insides of your input, so you'll have to select that input.

```
yourExistingSelector.querySelector("input").innerHTML
```

In your case:

```
table.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector("input").innerHTML
```